# remove google cache of thousand's of pages

Tags: google-search-console

Webmaster's tool have cache removal option but it allows to enter only one URL. I want to remove cache of around 50k url's. It's tedious job to do it 50k times.

Address of URL's is like following:
Say user profiles are being cached.
URL's are like "myinfo.com/profiles/1", "myinfo.com/profiles/2", "myinfo.com/profiles/3", "myinfo.com/profiles/4" and so on.

If I enter relative path http://myinfo.com/profiles/, will google remove cache of all profiles?
Or Is there any way to submit url's in bulk?

Comment: [Google Search Console API](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api-original/) might be worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've already figured out how to request removal of a single URL, that means it is out of the question here.

So, the next step in that process is it lets you request removal of an entire directory, if the file URLs are predictable in that particular manner. (Since you mentioned you have thousands of URLs, I'd hope they're at least somewhat organized.) So, try it out this way once.